# How to change the color of a draggable and gravitational UIView when touches the bottom edge of the screen

Tags: swift, uikit, gravity

I'm coding a simple game, basically the game starts with a blue square who falls after a few seconds and the user can drag it and drop it, and the square will fall again.

I would like to use a function that changes the color of the blue square when this touches the bottom edge of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class CanvasViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var blueSquare: UIView!
    
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
    var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
    var motion: CMMotionManager!

    var queue: OperationQueue! // used for updating UI objects with motion
    
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    
    let colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.green]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        queue = OperationQueue.current
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [blueSquare])
        
        motion = CMMotionManager()
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CanvasViewController.draggedView(_:)))
        blueSquare.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        blueSquare.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        
        // the objects that responds to collision
        let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [blueSquare])

        // the boundary AKA the borders. In this case if the full ViewController view
        collision.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "borders" as NSCopying, for: UIBezierPath(rect: self.view.frame))
        
        
        animator.addBehavior(collision)
        
        //Elasticity
        let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [blueSquare])
        bounce.elasticity = 8
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(blueSquare)
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        blueSquare.center = CGPoint(x: blueSquare.center.x + translation.x, y: blueSquare.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        
        animator.updateItem(usingCurrentState: blueSquare)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UICollisionBehavior` is the one who make a border at the bottom edge of the screen and start bouncing. So you need to take the delegate of `UICollisionBehavior` in order for you to know when need to change color

```swift
let colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.green]
var currentColorIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // your others code
    // the objects that responds to collision
    let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [blueSquare])
    collision.collisionDelegate = self // get collision delegate

    // the boundary AKA the borders. In this case if the full ViewController view
    collision.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "borders" as NSCopying, for: UIBezierPath(rect: self.view.frame))


    animator.addBehavior(collision)
}
```

Make a delegate for changing view color

```swift
extension CanvasViewController : UICollisionBehaviorDelegate {
    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
        // when it touch the bottom edge and the collision start
        currentColorIndex = currentColorIndex + 1 >= colors.count ? 0 : currentColorIndex + 1
        blueSquare.backgroundColor = colors[currentColorIndex]
    }

    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, endedContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?) {
        // when it bounce
    }
}
```

The result
[image: The result]